# pagination in react native listview

Tags: listview, react-native, pagination

```
<List dataArray={ComplaintStore.listdata.slice()} renderRow={(data)=>((data.length!=0)?
  <ListItem onPress={()=>this.onSelectComplaint(data)}>
    <View style={{flex:1,flexDirection: 'row'}}>
      <Text style={{color: 'black',fontSize:fsize}}>{data.id}</Text>
      <Text style={{color: 'black',fontSize:fsize}}>Type:{data.type}</Text>
      <Text style={{color: 'black',fontSize:fsize}}>Sub Type:{data.priority}</Text>
      <Text style={{marginRight:30,color: 'black',fontSize:fsize}}>{data.statusname}</Text>
    </View>
    </View>
  </ListItem>
  :
  <View></View>)}>
</List>
```

In the above listview ,due to more amount of list items `onPress` `ListItem` event takes 2-5 sec to trigger.

With Less listitems it is effective, problem on more than 30 listitems

How to resolve it , is pagination is helpfull?....

Answer (score 0):

For longer lists you should use [`FlatList`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html) - it optimizes rendering by rendering only what's actually shown on screen.

Comment: this is not an answer

Comment: @RishavKumar if you have specific criticism, please, share it. Otherwise, I think my answer resolves the problem of performance in long lists, which is what the OP asked about.

Comment: I really dont have an issue brother, but the question was how to implement pagination in list view

Comment: @RishavKumar read the question again. The OP complains about performance issues using a `ListView`. He then proceeds to ask "How to resolve it , is pagination is helpfull?". To me this means he wanted to know how to solve his issue, not necessarily how to implement pagination.

Comment: May be My bad! Flatlist performance is very good in sence of optimisation and everything